What is the best simple architecture to process distributed workload using Celery and MinIO?
I'm quite new to Celery and distributed task queue, I'm looking for some suggestion in regards best approach to utilize.
Concept:

as input I have lots of text file to process, divided in "slot" or folder
each folder will be uploaded in a Minio (or equivalent object store)
I will require to distribute task, potentially using Celery and python executor (I will require to perform some NER detection using Spacy)

This is how I think should be:

How can I add "sensor" to let Celery worker being triggered when new file/folder is uploaded?
Is there any best alternative?
Many thx in advance for any suggestion
